# Error when runing USB_OTG_FS with RTOS for pendrive application

Tags: stm32, host, freertos, usb-otg, fatfs

First of all I have run the project with STM32H745I + USB_OTG_FS + FATFS + MSHC for the pendrive application and it runs without any error, I am able to create a file, directrory & write into the file.

But when I add FreeRTOS in the same combination of existing project I can only mount the USB after that I stuck in HardFault handler. I don't know what the exact setting I have to do with FreeRTOS.

If anyone have idea please help me out.

Thanks!

Now, I want to run the pendrive in MSC mode with RTOS

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the location of the error. But the error may be returned because you are using the SysTick timebase. Try change it in the configuration menu to TIM1